# Need to clarify the use of pipe in batch file for a specific context

Tags: batch-file, pipe

I am working on NSCA to integrate passive alerts and checks from remote machines and applications with Nagios. On the internet, I have found a part of batch file code which could help perform it. However I don't understand the use of the pipe at the last line. I know how the pipe works but I cannot see how the output echo %1;%2;%3;"%4" will be using as input of values %NSCA_BIN% -H %NSCA_SERVER% -p 5667 -to 10 -c %NSCA_CFG% -d ; .

```
set NSCA_HOME="D:\Nagios\BIN\GATEWAY"
set NSCA_BIN=%NSCA_HOME%\send_nsca.exe
set NSCA_CFG=%NSCA_HOME%\send_nsca.cfg
set NSCA_SERVER="192.168.10.110"

echo %1;%2;%3;"%4" | %NSCA_BIN% -H %NSCA_SERVER% -p 5667 -to 10 -c %NSCA_CFG% -d ;
```

Can you enlighten to clarify this point (about the meaning of the use of this pipe) for me please? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, has your question been answered, or do you need anything else clarified?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it looks like `D:\Nagios\BIN\GATEWAY\send_nsca.exe` takes input from the user when run from a command line.  This script uses the values in %1 - %4 as the inputs as if the user had typed it.

Answer (score 0):

The variables **%1**, **%2**, **%3**, and **%4** are the first four space-delimited arguments provided on the command line to the script.

The part after the pipe evaluates to:

```
D:\Nagios\BIN\GATEWAY\send_nsca.exe -H 192.168.10.110 -p 5667 -to 10 -c D:\Nagios\BIN\GATEWAY\send_nsca.cfg -d ;
```

[Documentation for **send_nsca**](http://search.cpan.org/~dougdude/Net-NSCA-Client-0.006/bin/send_nsca) says that it takes data from standard input consisting of Nagios Service Host, Nagios Service Description, Status Number, and Plugin Output separated by tabs or a delimiter specified with the **-d** switch. The command above sets the delimiter to `;`.

The part before the pipe, `echo %1;%2;%3;"%4"`, takes the four command line arguments, separates them with colons, quotes the last one, and feeds them as input to **send_nsca**. That means you'd call the script like this:

```
scriptname.bat NagiosServiceHost NagiosServiceDescription StatusNumber PluginOutput
```

The purpose of the script appears to be to save you the trouble of having to type out the path to **send_nsca** and all the command line arguments, and simply provide the input, which is useful if you use this command multiple times.

---

I seems to me, though, that there's an error in the way the batch file is written. Nothing I see in the docs specifies that the fourth field of the input (plugin output) needs to be quoted, so I presume that the idea behind quoting **%4** is to allow the plugin output specified on the command line to contain spaces. However, this won't work, because the batch file assigns space-delimited tokens from the command line to the **%#** variables, so **%4** will only contain the fourth token, and everything after a space that follows it will be ignored.

I think the quotes should be taken out, and if you need to supply an argument with spaces, quote it on the command line at the time you invoke the batch file, like this:

```
scriptname.bat NagiosServiceHost NagiosServiceDescription StatusNumber "Plugin Output With Spaces"
```

This would set **%4** to `"Plugin Output With Spaces"` (yes, the quotes are included in the value of the variable -- which is what you want).

Comment: Unfortunately, `%*` does not mean `"all remaining arguments"` - it means `"all arguments"`. I believe you are confusing this with the `tokens` optionof the `for/f` command. Now, as an idea, `for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%a in ('echo %*') do ...` may be viable.

Comment: @PeterWright Oh, you're right. I done very little batch scripting (if batch even merits being called "scripting") since I started using PowerShell, and have gotten a little rusty. The **%\*** will duplicate the first three arguments. I wouldn't call it "unfortunate", though, because I felt that quoting arguments when invoking the batch file is the better approach anyway. I'll take that out of the answer.